# Store output of lsblk command key=value into associative array in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```sh
> lsblk -Po mountpoint,label,uuid /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Output from the lsblk example command:

MOUNTPOINT="/media/user/GParted Live" LABEL="GParted Live" UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I will be using above command in bash and I want to store the key values in `partition` associative array. The above lsblk output therefore needs to be processed and placed in an associative array 
Like - 
`partition[MOUNTPOINT]` should have `/media/user/GParted Live` 
`partition[LABEL]` should have `GParted Live` 
`partition[UUID]` should have `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Can someone please help by giving me a readable bash script?

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Try the following: source <(awk 'BEGIN { FPAT="[[:upper:]]+=\"([[:alnum:]]|[/]|[-]|[[:space:]])?+\"";print "declare -A partition" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,map,"=");print "partition[\""map[1]"\"]="map[2] } }' <(lsblk -Po mountpoint,label,uuid /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx))

Comment: To improve your prospects of getting a good answer, it is generally a good idea to make it easier for folks to help you - so maybe consider providing sample output from your `lsblk` command so people can see what you are dealing with.

Comment: He has. He wants to format the output of the lsblk command in such as way that it forms an associative array called partition with indexes, MOUNTPOINT, LABEL and UUID. Not sure why it has been closed to be honest,

Comment: Oh, I see. My apologies. I took that to be a part of the command, rather than the command followed by the output.

Comment: @RamanSailopal getting correct output for UUID but not correctly for MOUNTPOINT and LABEL because it contains space.

Comment: Space should be accounted for in field pattern (FPAT). I've tried it with your test output and it worked OK for me. I also tried it locally on my system with no issues?

Comment: source <(awk 'BEGIN { FPAT="[[:upper:]]+=\"([[:alnum:]]|[/]|[-]|[[:space:]])?+\"";print "declare -A partition" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,map,"=");print "partition[\""map[1]"\"]="map[2] } }' <<< 'MOUNTPOINT="/media/user/GParted Live" LABEL="GParted Live" UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the `lsblk` output does not contain double quotes (`"`) embedded in the 'value' strings
- for this answer I'm going to place OP's `lsblk` output into a file (`lsblk.out`) and use said file as input to the proposed answer.

Sample input data:

```
$ cat lsblk.out
MOUNTPOINT="/media/user/GParted Live" LABEL="GParted Live" UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

We'll start with a `sed` solution that uses a capture group to break the input into separate lines:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^ ][A-Z]*=\"[^\"]*\")[ $]/\1\n/g' lsblk.out
MOUNTPOINT="/media/user/GParted Live"
LABEL="GParted Live"
UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

We'll then feed this to a `while` loop to populate our array:

```
unset partition
declare -A partition

while IFS="=" read -r idx data
do
    partition[${idx}]="${data}"
done < <(sed -E 's/([^ ][A-Z]*=\"[^\"]*\")[ $]/\1\n/g' lsblk.out)
```

We can then check the results of the operation :

```
$ typeset -p partition
declare -A partition=([UUID]="\"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\"" [LABEL]="\"GParted Live\"" [MOUNTPOINT]="\"/media/user/GParted Live\"" )
```

Alternatively:

```
for idx in "${!partition[@]}"
do
    echo "${idx} : ${partition[${idx}]}"
done
```

Which generates:

```
UUID : "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
LABEL : "GParted Live"
MOUNTPOINT : "/media/user/GParted Live"
```

---

If OP wants to strip out the double quotes (`"`):

```
while IFS="=" read -r idx data
do
    partition[${idx}]="${data//\"/}"               # strip out double quotes
done < <(sed -E 's/([^ ][A-Z]*=\"[^\"]*\")[ $]/\1\n/g' lsblk.out)
```

Then verify:

```
typeset -p partition

for idx in "${!partition[@]}"
do
    echo "${idx} : ${partition[${idx}]}"
done
```

Which generates:

```
declare -A partition=([UUID]="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" [LABEL]="GParted Live" [MOUNTPOINT]="/media/user/GParted Live" )

UUID : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
LABEL : GParted Live
MOUNTPOINT : /media/user/GParted Live
```

---

OP should be able to feed the `lsblk` command into the `while` loop like such:

```
while IFS="=" read -r idx data
do
    partition[${idx}]="${data}"
#   partition[${idx}]="${data//\"/}"
done < <(lsblk -Po mountpoint,label,uuid /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx | sed -E 's/([^ ][A-Z]*=\"[^\"]*\")[ $]/\1\n/g')
```

**NOTE**: to remove double quotes (`"`) move the comment (`#`) up one line